# Correctness of "Live by rumors"

Tags: prepositions, phrases, grammaticality-in-context, prepositional-phrases

Is the preposition used correctly or should there be another one? And is the phrase clear?

I want to say that the person believes in rumors, not facts.

> Live by rumors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preposition is used correctly, in my view, although a bit weird. I didn't understand what you were saying without the explanation so it might be useful to expand your statement a little to make it clearer. "Live by" is used more often with a large guiding principle, such as "faith" or "virtue", rather than "rumors" or "facts". Perhaps rephrase to make your statement's meaning more obvious, but grammatically speaking it's correct.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how explain it better

Comment: @Boyep You just did! You could say "rather than living by truth, believing in facts, [s/he/they/name] believed in rumors." Something like that?